# Why in T-SQL some unicode characters are equal to nothing?

Tags: sql, string, t-sql, unicode

In my database i have translation table which contains dictionary for converting unusual Unicode characters to english character. Unicode character is primary key of this table.
And some time ago i faced an issue: some different Unicode characters are the same for T-SQL and they are equal to nothing at the same time.

I can find the way do distinguish one from another ('=' is useless) and even managed to insert one of them into database. But i can`t insert more then one because of primary key constrain while they all are equal.

I discovered just 4: Ș ș Ț ț. But 4 is just enough to spoil my system.

And this is the short but informative example of how do they behave:

```
DECLARE @Strings TABLE(id int, ucode nvarchar(50))
INSERT INTO @Strings (id, ucode)
    SELECT 1, N'A' UNION -- Usual char
    SELECT 2, N'Ы' UNION -- Some unicode char    
    SELECT 3, N'Ф' UNION -- Another unicode char
    SELECT 5, N' ' UNION -- space
    SELECT 6, N'Ș' UNION -- Unusual unicode char
    SELECT 7, N'Ț' UNION -- Unusual unicode char
    SELECT 8, N'some_string' UNION      -- example string
    SELECT 9, N'some_string ' UNION     -- example string with space
    SELECT 10, N'some_string Ș' UNION   -- example string with unusual char
    SELECT 11, N'some_string Ț'         -- one more

 SELECT * FROM @Strings
 SELECT * FROM @Strings WHERE ucode = N'A'  -- Good one (1 result)
 SELECT * FROM @Strings WHERE ucode = N'Ș'  -- Magic (3 results)
 SELECT * FROM @Strings WHERE ucode = N'Ț'  -- Magic (3 results)
 SELECT * FROM @Strings WHERE ucode = ''    -- Magic (3 results)
 SELECT * FROM @Strings WHERE ucode = 'some_string' -- Magic (4 results)
```

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: What collation are you using and what version are you on?

Comment: Martin Smith, I tryied on  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS and Cyrillic_General_CI_AS

Comment: Also what are your desired semantics for case and accent sensitivity?

Comment: Martin Smith, case and accent sensitive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`=` isn't useless, but you need to specify how `=` should compare. The default is set at the database level, and your column does not specify different comparison rules, so your column gets the database's comparison rules. Primary keys use the same comparison rules as `=`, so fixing it for one also makes the other work as you intend it to.

Specifying the comparison rules is done with the [`COLLATE` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184391.aspx). One collation that should treat all code points as distinct characters is `Latin1_General_BIN2`.

```
DECLARE @Strings TABLE(id int, ucode nvarchar(50) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2)
```